# returns the last row for a given day with the same title/ticketID

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to apply a query to the database in such a way that it returns the last row for a given day with the same title/ticketID.

Example

| ID | TicketID | Date | Title | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01.02.2020 | Fruit is green | new |
| 2 | 111 | 01.02.2020 | Fruit is green | open |
| 3 | 111 | 03.02.2020 | Fruit is green | open - wait |
| 4 | 111 | 03.02.2020 | Fruit is green | close |
| 5 | 222 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | new |
| 6 | 222 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | open |
| 7 | 222 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | open - wait |
| 8 | 222 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | close |
| 9 | 333 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | close |
| 10 | 444 | 05.02.2020 | Fruit is blue | new |
| 11 | 555 | 05.02.2020 | Fruit is red | open |
| 12 | 555 | 05.02.2020 | Fruit is red | open - wait |
| 13 | 666 | 06.02.2020 | Fruit is red | close |
| 14 | 777 | 06.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | new |
| 15 | 777 | 07.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | open |
| 16 | 777 | 08.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | open - wait |

I would like it to return something like this when I enter a query into the database:

| ID | TicketID | Date | Title | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 111 | 01.02.2020 | Fruit is green | open |
| 4 | 111 | 03.02.2020 | Fruit is green | close |
| 8 | 222 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | close |
| 9 | 333 | 04.02.2020 | Fruit is yellow | close |
| 10 | 444 | 05.02.2020 | Fruit is blue | new |
| 12 | 555 | 05.02.2020 | Fruit is red | open - wait |
| 13 | 666 | 06.02.2020 | Fruit is red | close |
| 14 | 777 | 06.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | new |
| 15 | 777 | 07.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | open |
| 16 | 777 | 08.02.2020 | Fruit is pink | open - wait |

So

1. does not eliminate duplicates with a ticketID if the days are different
2. eliminates duplicates if the ticketID is repeated on the same day
3. takes the last ticketID for the day among the duplicates with the ticketID

What have I tried?

I tried applying with this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, TicketID, Date, Title, Status
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        TicketID, 
        Date, Title, 
        Status, 
        row_number() over (partition by ticketID group by date order by id desc) TEMP
    FROM
        MyTableFruit
    GROUP BY 
        Date
)
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND
    Temp = 1
ORDER BY
    Date;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as I assumed this would take the last ticketID from duplicate ticketIDs for the day....

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses from the inner query and give the `ROW_NUMBER ...` column an alias using `AS rn` at the end of the line and then, in the outer query, use `WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: @MT0 I added RN before but as just the name "TEMP" I forgot to add here to the post, I corrected but it is not what I expect.... It will return me the last TicketID but will not group for a given day.

Comment: `SELECT ID, TicketID, "DATE", Title, Status FROM ( SELECT ID, TicketID,  "DATE", Title,  Status, row_number() over (partition by ticketID, TRUNC("DATE") order by id desc) AS TEMP FROM MyTableFruit ) WHERE Temp = 1 ORDER BY "DATE";` (Also, don't use `DATE` as an identifier as it is a reserved word.)